# How to populate Listbox datavaluefield with multiple fields

Tags: vb.net

--VB.NET----

Kindly help me this

I need to populate listbox datavaluefield with multiple field. The value will be coming to datatable - (dataset). I can't change the sql statement because it is under stored proc that uses globally

```
lstSearchResult.DataSource = dt
lstSearchResult.DataValueField = "EMP_ID" & "LNAME" &"ADD" ->> could it be possible
lstSearchResult.DataTextField = "LNAME"
lstSearchResult.DataBind()
```

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Spin through the DataTable and add a new ListItem for each DataRow, concatenating the different fields when making the ListItems.  You can't bind two fields as the DataValueField.